# Rewrite code using a linked list instead an a 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, singly-linked-list

I need to rewrite this code that uses a 2D array using a singly linked list.  I thought I could just step through the list in the same way that this code steps through the matrix but it doesn't work and stops when trying to read a 2x2 array.  Here is the original code with the array version:

Input looks likes this, the order is listed above each matrix:

1

5

2

2 3

5 9

```
public class Determinant {

  public static int calculate(LinkedList matrix, int order) { 
    int det = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int new_order= 0;
    int rows = 0;
    int a = 0;

        if (matrix.size() == 1) {
    a = (int)matrix.get(1);
            return a; 
        } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < order; i++){// minor matrix is one order less than matrix
                LinkedList minor = new LinkedList();
                    while (rows < order) {

                    //build the minor matrix, ignoring the first row 
                    for (int j = 1; j < order; j++) {
                        if (matrix.get(z)!= null) {
                            int y = z + order;
                            minor.add(matrix.get(y));
                        }z++;
                    }rows++;

                 }// determinant calculated with recursive call 
                new_order = order-1;
                a = (int) matrix.get(i);
                det += a*Math.pow(-1,i)*calculate(minor, new_order);
            }
        }return det;
}
```

I can at least get it to run when I take the recursive part out, but when I put it back it it gets stuck on the 2x2 matrix.  I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at listdeterminant.Matrix.calculat

Comment: Using a LinkedList for something like this seems like a serious performance issue.

Comment: If you don't have consent about performance, Since public static int calculate(int[][] matrix) working fine, try to convert (LinkedList matrix) into (int[][] matrix).

Comment: It is a huge performance issue.  That's part of the problem. I would rather do an array for sure but the task says to rewrite it not convert it.